# Bower styles are not included in Yeoman Angular project

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, yeoman, bower

I am completely new to Yeoman so I am still figuring out the workflow.  When I set up my application using `yo angular` it prompted to pick my options. I wanted to use Sass Twitter Bootstrap and Compass so I included it in my project.  At the bottom of the `index.html` page that was generated I can see this:

```
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/affix.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/alert.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/button.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/collapse.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/tab.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/transition.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/scrollspy.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/modal.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/popover.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Which is what I expect to see.  All of the files I have asked for in my project being included.

However, at the top I see this

```
<!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
<!-- bower:css -->
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

This is baffling.  I expect to see all of my files there from bower just like I do with my JS.

I've looked around but couldn't find anything on how to actually make this work or what that block of code is actually there for.  Do I need to make a `vendor.scss` file somewhere?

How come my bower styles aren't being included?  How do I automate this within Yeoman?

Comment: Did you try making a vendor.scss file?

Comment: @cimmanon Yes I did and I figured that's where I would include my bower styles.  However when I rebuild my project, it's not being populated in that block.